# Self-dual $126$ and $126^*$ in SO(10) or Spin(10) Irreps

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

We are looking at 126 or $126^*$ in SO(10) or Spin(10) Irreps.

126 is known as a complex total "anti-symmetric" and "self-dual" 5-index tensor irreps in Spin(10). This means the component of 126 is from the counting of anti-symmetric 5-index tensor
$$\frac{1}{2}{10 \choose 5}=126.
$$ I am puzzled by some statements of the Georgi book *Lie Algebras in Particle Physics 2nd ed -- From Isospin to Unified Theories.*

My questions are:

1. If 126 in Spin(10) irrep is self-dual, would 126 and  $126^*$ be the same or different?
2. But it looks that in Georgi book (23.41)and (24.12), it said that
   $$
   16 x 16  = 10 + 120 + 126,
   $$
   which is different from https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10969 Table A.79, said
   $$
   16 x 16  = 10 + 120 + 126^*.
   $$
   So are 126 and $126^*$ the same or different? Why Gerogi seemed to suggest 126 and $126^*$ are the same?

3. The 126 is a complex total "anti-symmetric self-dual" 5-index tensor. But I am not sure why Gerogi said that it is symmetric in some way, saying the
   $(5)$ as 5-index tensor of the symmetry of $\Gamma_j Rs$ of SU(11)? See below. What does this mean?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. The modules $126$ and $126^*$ are different. The one has highest weight $2\lambda_4$, the other $2\lambda_5$. The graph automorphism interchanges them.
2. $16$ is different from $16^*$, which are $\lambda_4$ and $\lambda_5$. Indeed, we see $L(2\lambda_4)$ in the symmetric square of $L(\lambda_4)$.
3. The tensor square of a module breaks up as the exterior square and the symmetric square. The symmetric square of $16$ is $10\oplus 126$, i.e., $L(\lambda_1)\oplus L(2\lambda_4)$, and the exterior square is $120=L(\lambda_3)$. It appears symmetrically presumably means it is a submodule of the symmetric square.

Comment: Thanks I do not understand something about the above texts. It says "$(1)$ and $(5)$ are symmetric, and the (3) is antisymmetric." The $(5)$ is exactly the 126, so what is it  symmetric about?

Comment: also I voted up, thanks!

Comment: See point 3. $120$ is the exterior square, which is the antisymmetric part under the $S_2$-action. $10\oplus 126$ is the symmetric part under the action, i.e., the symmetric square.

Comment: In your notation, do you know which of $2\lambda_4$ or $2\lambda_5$ is the 126 in 16 $\times$ 16=10+120+"126"?

Comment: Yes. The symmetric square of $L(\lambda_i)$ has $L(2\lambda_i)$ in it, in general. (And it's not my notation, it's the standard notation for discussing highest weight modules. See, for example, Bourbaki.)

Comment: thanks I will accept in a week if no better insights!

Comment: can you look into this https:// math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773876/8-8-dimensional-representations-and-mutation many thanks!

Comment: I already answered it. You are trying to understand representations of these groups from a physics textbook rather than from a group representation theory textbook. You might have more luck on a physic forum because even your language for the terms is not what I would call standard.

Comment: yes that is the thing I need some helps. because I find your language seems related to the answer I wanted but I need to know how to translate to what I knew before on physics group theory textbook

Comment: I am using the language of this paper arxiv.org/abs/1912.10969 if you find my words not standard to you...

Comment: Look at the Dynkin label in the table. For large-rank groups, rather than writing 001000000 we write $\lambda_3$. So Dynkin label 00100 becomes $\lambda_3$. $L(\lambda_3)$ is just the simple module with Dynkin label 00100.

Comment: Can you please try to answer this (even one more time) if you can math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773876/8-8-dimensional-representations-and-mutation I wonder does it make sense to relabel the 8v, 8s, 8c in that paper arxiv.org/abs/1912.10969 as I asked in my post 3773876 ?

Comment: There is no question in that post. Different modules restrict differently to subgroups. The $8$-dimensional modules are related by an automorphism, but the subgroup you are restricting to is not stabilized by that automorphism, so you shouldn't expect any relationship between the restrictions.